# SQLAlchemy - Special Characters in MySQL Table Names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating MySQL tables dynamically with the following code SQL Alchemy code:

```
meta = Base.metadata
table_data = Table(
    table_name, meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('file_name', String(250), nullable=False))
)
meta.create_all(engine, [table_data])
```

The `table_name` variable is a unique string sent via an API POST call. The problem is that the table name can contain special characters, which I cannot change.

If I try to manually create the name via MySQL workbench, it works fine. But it will throw an error when I do it via SQL Alchemy. Can anybody advise how to make it work? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Here is an example, with the error for name `data_E82sR4g5YtXqv@AT2QIwH4bQ==`:

```
(MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, '')
[SQL: drop table if exists data_E82sR4g5YtXqv@AT2QIwH4bQ==]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: Please include the error (with its traceback) and an example of a name that fails.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - Added. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using pandas? What's the actual code that produces that error? The traceback would answer some of these as well, if not omitted.

Comment: Did you try the `quote` option to the `Table` constructor? The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) has more information about that.

Comment: @IljaEverilä -  am not using Pandas and the only response I get is what is posted above - Please notice that the application works just fine with table names not including special characters.

Comment: @Dirk - Thanks for the suggestion. I used both quote and quote_schema, still with the same results.

Comment: I've had the impression that `meta.create_all(engine, [table_data])` would not drop an existing table, and hence think that the above code example is not a [mcve] given the error, and so would like to see the full traceback.